# What happened to the Style 'Subchapter' in Mathematica 12.0?

Tags: style

The Style 'Subchapter' is no longer available in the Style Menu in Mathematica 12.0.

Is it somewhere hidden perhaps? I want to continue styling notebooks as I did in Mma 11.3 and before.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It seems it lost its shortcut in favor of `"Subtitle"` style.

Comment: Opening an 11.3 Notebook in 12.0 displays the old Subchapter format correctly, but I can't create it anymore, besides copy / paste.

Comment: You can modify the stylesheet or use Ctrl+0 and enter Subchapter there, nice thing is that it will be preserved.

Comment: Well.. you can use the Chapter style and then, with your cursor at the beginning on the line, press TAB.

Comment: That does it! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gustavo Delfino answered as follows:

Use the Chapter style and then, with your cursor at the beginning on the line, press TAB.

This generates the Subchapter as familiar in 11.3 and prior.